Django transaction is splitted, even if I use transaction.atomic()
    with transaction.atomic():
        A.objects.filter(
            a=a,
            b=b,
            c=c,
            d__range=[start_date, end_date],
        ).delete()


        A.objects.bulk_create(
            [
                A(
                    a=a,
                    b=b,
                    c=c,
                    d=d,
                    e=e,
                    f=f,
                    g=g,
                )
                for obj in objs 
            ]
        )

Query is like
BEGIN
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ...
COMMIT
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ...
COMMIT
What I want to do
BEGIN
DELETE FROM ...
INSERT INTO
COMMIT

What database are you using?

@KirillIlichev postgresql, thanks
